# Recycle view inside cardview aren't visible

Tags: java, android

I tried to insert recycleview inside cardview, but it not create it. I think it's problem with adapter, because this type of card created, but not fill recycle view.Now its look like this[image: Now its look like this]

There's my recycleview adapter code

```
public class SubItemsAdapter extends      RecyclerView.Adapter<SubItemsAdapter.SubtasksViewHolder>{
private List<Subtask> subtasks;

public SubItemsAdapter(List<Subtask> subtasks){
    this.subtasks = subtasks;
}

public class SubtasksViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView titleTextView;
    CheckBox doneCheckBox;

    public SubtasksViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        titleTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtaskTitle);
        doneCheckBox = (CheckBox)itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtaskCheckbox);
    }
}

@Override
public SubtasksViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.subtasks_listitem,parent,false);
    return new SubtasksViewHolder(v);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SubtasksViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.titleTextView.setText(subtasks.get(position).getText());
    holder.doneCheckBox.setChecked(subtasks.get(position).getDone());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return subtasks.size();
}} `
```

And my cardview code:

```
public class TasklistAdapter extends                          RecyclerView.Adapter<TasklistAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<TodoItem> todoItems;
int[] dataTypes;
private static final int SIMPLETODOITEM = 0;
private static final int EXTENDTODOITEM = 1;
Context context;

public TasklistAdapter(ArrayList<TodoItem> todoItems, int[] dataTypes, Context context)
{
    this.todoItems = todoItems;
    this.dataTypes = dataTypes;
    this.context = context;
}

public class SimpleViewHolder extends ViewHolder{
    TextView titleTextView;
    TextView desciptionTextView;
    CheckBox doneCheckBox;

    public SimpleViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        titleTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.simpleitem_title_textbox);
        desciptionTextView =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.simpleitem_description_textbox);
        doneCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.simpleitem_checkbox);
    }
}

public class ExtendViewHolder extends ViewHolder{
    TextView titleTextView;
    TextView descTextView;
    RecyclerView subtasksListView;
    SubItemsAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;
    public ExtendViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        titleTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.extended_card_title);
        descTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.extended_card_description);
        subtasksListView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.subtasks_listview);
        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(v.getContext());
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    switch (viewType)
    {
        case EXTENDTODOITEM:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.extendedtodoitem_card, parent, false);
            return new ExtendViewHolder(v);
        default:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.simpletodoitem_card,parent,false);
            return new SimpleViewHolder(v);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
        case EXTENDTODOITEM:
            ExtendViewHolder extViewHold = (ExtendViewHolder)holder;
            extViewHold.adapter = new SubItemsAdapter(todoItems.get(position).getSubtasks());
            extViewHold.titleTextView.setText(todoItems.get(position).getText());
            extViewHold.descTextView.setText(todoItems.get(position).getDescription());
            extViewHold.subtasksListView.setLayoutManager(extViewHold.manager);
            extViewHold.subtasksListView.setAdapter(extViewHold.adapter);
            break;
        default:
            SimpleViewHolder simViewHold = (SimpleViewHolder)holder;
            simViewHold.desciptionTextView.setText(todoItems.get(position).getDescription());
            simViewHold.titleTextView.setText(todoItems.get(position).getText());
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return todoItems.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return dataTypes[position];
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
    }
}
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

in your  TasklistAdapter, `static class ViewHolder extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder` seems useless! and you are trying to inflate and bind data with two heterogeneous layouts with their own viewholder sub-classes! My solution would be to change this :

```
public class TasklistAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<TasklistAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

to

```
public class TasklistAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

Comment: As I think it's not solve the problem because it's only excess code. Anyway  my ViewHolder class extend from RecycleView.ViewHolder and that's why it should work.